# Test of question

Tags: calculus

For each natural number $n$, let $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k(n)$ be a convergent series. If for each k, $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_k(n)=a_k$, and $\displaystyle \vert a_k(n)\vert \leq M_k$ for all n where the series $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}M_k$  converges, then
$$ \displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k(n)  = \ \  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k $$

Comment: This is dominated convergence theorem applied to the counting measure on $\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 2):

This is also known as the Weierstrass M test.

See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test

Comment: Ok guy's , I was testing the Math Jax Resources!